# Why is iOS' MPMoviePlayerViewController doing so many requests?

Tags: iphone, http, mpmovieplayercontroller

I scooped the traffic when starting a video from the iPhone (YouTube app) and noticed a lot of small byte-range requests, before the actual request is done that downloads the bulk of the video (and playback starts). See screenshot of HTTPScoop (I routed the iPhone's traffic through my computer).

[image]

Now, in my own app, I'm also trying to playback video from the web, and even more small byte-range requests are done before the actual playback starts:
[image]

I got a feeling all those requests are delaying the playback (the moment the playback starts seems to be correlated with the largest byte range, which often happens after 10-20 secs....)

Why is iOS' MPMoviePlayerViewController doing so many requests?